# Reading yaml file in bash script and running commands with yaml-values as parameters

Tags: bash, shell, yaml, swagger

I am trying to create a "codegen" script that read a .yaml file and generates api.ts files based on the values in the yaml files.

I want to write my yaml-file like so:

```
dbaas:
  url: http://rackerlabs.github.io/wadl2swagger/openstack/swagger/dbaas.json
flavor-access:
  url: http://rackerlabs.github.io/wadl2swagger/openstack/swagger/flavor-access-v2.1.json
```

The yaml-file can have any amount of entries, but its always in the "name".url format.

Given this yaml I want the script to run the follwing commands:

`curl -k http://rackerlabs.github.io/wadl2swagger/openstack/swagger/dbaas.json -o dbaas-swagger.json`

then

`npx swagger-typescript-api -p dbaas-swagger.json -n dbaasApi.ts`

Then the same for flavor-access. This should then leave me with two api files: `dbaasApi.ts` and `flavor-accessApi.ts`

I tried to get help from ChatGPT but its scripts keep giving this error from `curl`: `curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`

Here is the script it made:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=: read -r key value; do
  if [[ "$key" =~ [a-zA-Z0-9_]+ ]]; then
    top_node="${key// /}"
    read -r url
    swagger_url="${url// /}"

    json_path="${top_node}-swagger.json"
    api_ts="${top_node}Api.ts"

    curl -k "$swagger_url" -o "$json_path"
    echo "Downloaded swagger JSON for $top_node"

    npx swagger-typescript-api -p "$json_path" -n "$api_ts"
    echo "Generated TypeScript API for $top_node"
  fi
done < ./swagger-codegen.yaml
```

Comment: Use a proper YAML parser like yq and get the values of the node and the URL and iterate it over a shell loop and run the commands needed

Comment: Could you give an example implementation? I'm unfamiliar with yq

Comment: Can you post the actual command you want to run with `npx` and `curl`? i.e. the values for URL and path? It is unclear with your attempt above

Comment: **If** the yaml file always consists of 4 lines in exactly this structure, I would not read it line-by-line, but just do a `grep -o` for the _https_ parts. If the yaml file can be more general, I would use a parser. If you don't want to use yq, you can use a programming language such as Ruby or Perl, which come with a Yaml-Parser builtin. [Here](https://perlmaven.com/read-yaml-file) is a Perl example, and [this](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html) is for Ruby.

Comment: Updated question with real values you could try in a script

Answer (score 1):

With a valid YAML processor like [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), parsing YAML contents become trivial. Define a DSL query (yq specific) to output the node and the URL in a CSV format and use a shell loop to iterate on top of it

```bash
while IFS=',' read -r node url; do
    json_path="${node}-swagger.json"
    if ! curl --fail -k "$url" -o "${json_path}"; then
        break
    fi
    npx swagger-typescript-api -p "$json_path" -n "${node}Api.ts"
done < <(yq '(keys | .[]) as $k | [$k, .[$k].url] | join(",")' ./swagger-codegen.yaml)
```

Comment: Thanks. This works great but I really want to avoid using tools that need to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

I went with @user1934428 suggestion and just used `grep` since the yaml-structure is so simple.

Here is the final script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
  if [[ "$line" =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+: ]]; then
    top_node=$(echo "$line" | sed -E 's/[: ]//g')
    url=$(grep -A 1 "$top_node:" ./swagger-codegen.yaml | grep "url:" | sed 's/url:[ ]*//;s/^[ \t]*//')

    json_path="${top_node}-swagger.json"
    api_ts="${top_node}Api.ts"

    curl -k "$url" -o "$json_path"
    echo "✅ Downloaded swagger JSON for $top_node"

    npx swagger-typescript-api -p "$json_path" -n "$api_ts"
    echo "✅ Generated TypeScript API for $top_node"
  fi
done < ./swagger-codegen.yaml
```

The error causing the "curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL" message was due to leading spaces before the url. Just had to remove those using `sed`